# I query my sqlite database and got the result as [ ] (blank) even when my database has the data I tried to query

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask

I query my sqlite database and got the result as [ ] (blank) even when my database has the data I tried to query.

So I connected my Python file with my SQLite database (it connects fine) and query the data the user input through a form that is shown through using Jinja syntax on the HTML file:

```
import os and some other not important things


MYDIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
SQLPATH = os.path.join(MYDIR, "..", "data.sqlite")
conn = _sqlite3.connect(SQLPATH, check_same_thread=False)  
c = conn.cursor()




core = Blueprint('core', __name__)


@core.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    # Call a function to later use in creating the template
    search = Blogsearch_form(request.form)
    print(search.data)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM blog_post WHERE problem_name LIKE(?)", ('%' + str(search.data) + '%',))
        results = c.fetchall()
        print(results)
        return render_template('blog_search_result.html', results=results)

        # return blog_search_results(search)

    page = request.args.get('page',1,type=int)
    many_posts = BlogPost.query.order_by(BlogPost.date.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=10)
    return render_template('index.html', many_posts=many_posts, form=search)
```

You can see that I put 2 prints inside my codes to test and here is the results of those prints:
**print(search.data): {'search': 'New Life 3 check'}** (New Life 3 check is the input I type in the HTML form)

**print(results): [ ]**

Below is my Blogsearch_form's python file:

```
from wtforms import Form, StringField
class Blogsearch_form(Form):
    search = StringField('')
```

The part that shows the form on my HTML file:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 text-right" method=POST>
            {{ render_field(form.search) }}
           <input type=submit value=Search>
        </form>
```

The results should show all the data in the row that has the column prolem_name that contain words of "New Life 3 check". This row is inside a table called "blog_post", which is in the database "data.sqlite". However, as I show above, it give out a blank [ ]. I stuck on this for a while and I would greatly appreciate if you could help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this line should be

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM blog_post WHERE problem_name LIKE(?)", ('%' + str(search.search.data) + '%',))
```

instead of

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM blog_post WHERE problem_name LIKE(?)", ('%' + str(search.data) + '%',))
```

because you are trying to get the data of a field instead of the whole form. Also I would suggest you to provide more readable names of the variables!

Comment: It worked!!!!! Yes, it worked, thank you!!! I will rename the search variable:))

Comment: Hi Kartikeya, I have another problem related to python and sqlite and I'm hoping if you could also help me in it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61886605/13097721 Thank you!