# How can I get the blog_id of the rows of the sqlite table I just query and used? (In a Python file)

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the **codes** below that let users on my website to search for blogs. With the current, my HTML page will only show a list of data from all the row that has columns that match with the search input. But, I want to get the blog_id of all the matching rows that I just query with c.fetchall().

How would I do it? Should I write some codes right after I query data?... I would greatly appreciate if you help me. Also, if possible, could you show me how can I set the codes below to only query those rows that have a column that match the searching data?   :

```
many_posts = BlogPost.query.order_by(BlogPost.date.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=10)
(These codes above are placed inside the "if request.method == 'POST':")
```

**My codes (Python):**

```
import os 
import _sqlite3

MYDIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
SQLPATH = os.path.join(MYDIR, "..", "data.sqlite")
conn = _sqlite3.connect(SQLPATH, check_same_thread=False)  

c = conn.cursor()

@core.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    # Call a function to later use in creating the template
    form = Blogsearch_form(request.form)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM blog_post WHERE problem_name LIKE(?)", ('%' + str(form.search.data) + '%',))
        results = c.fetchall()
        page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
        many_posts = BlogPost.query.order_by(BlogPost.date.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=10)
        return render_template('blog_search_result.html', results=results, many_posts=many_posts)



    page = request.args.get('page',1,type=int)
    many_posts = BlogPost.query.order_by(BlogPost.date.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=10)
    return render_template('index.html', many_posts=many_posts, form=form)
```

My codes of the BlogPost's database creation:

```
class BlogPost(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'blog_post'
    users = db.relationship(User)

    blog_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False) #users.id  is taken from the tablename(users) and id in its table
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)  
    problem_name = db.Column(db.String(140), nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    blog_image = db.Column(db.String(140), nullable=False, server_default='default_blog.jpg')


    def __init__(self, text, problem_name, user_id, blog_image):
        self.text = text
        self.problem_name = problem_name
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.blog_image = blog_image



    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post ID: {self.post_id} -- Date:{self.date}---{self.problem_name}"
```

Part of my HTML codes:

```
    <h4>Search results:</h4>
    <h5>{{ results }}</h5>
   <p><small class="text-muted">If you see [ ] as the result, it means Upchanges have no relating problems to your search</small></p>

<div class="container row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 text-center">
{% for post in many_posts.items%}

    <div class="card border-dark mb-3 " style="width: 20rem;">
     <div class="card-body ">
         <h7><a class="text-warning" href="{{ url_for('users.user_posts', username=post.creator.first_name+post.creator.middle_name+post.creator.last_name) }}"><img class="text-center rounded" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/'+ post.creator.profile_image) }}" width = "35" height = "35" alt=""> {{ post.creator.first_name}} {{ post.creator.middle_name }} {{ post.creator.last_name }}</a></h7>
         <p></p>
         <img class="text-center rounded responsive1" alt="" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='blog_pics/'+ post.blog_image) }}" width = "495" height = "250">
         {# Need caution for post.blog_image on the code above #}
         <p></p>
         <h2><a class="card-tittle text-body problem" href="{{ url_for('blog_posts.blog_view', blog_validated_id=post.blog_id) }}">{{ post.problem_name[0:40]}}..</a></h2>
         <p class="card-text">{{ post.text[0:100] }}</p>
         <p><small class="text-muted">Posted on: {{ post.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}</small></p>
         <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{ url_for('blog_posts.blog_view', blog_validated_id=post.blog_id) }}">Read more</a>
     </div>


    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Additionally, all of my current codes are working fine and showing no errors.

Comment: to make it easier to help.

Could you please add following information to your question.

1.) Show also the importsm that declare `db`  to show us what python module you use for the ORM)
Is this sqlalchemy?

Comment: Yes, I'm using sqlalchemy sqlite and I use import sqlite3. And thank you so much for helping me!!

Comment: please post also a small html template file, that contains the bare minimum to show the problem. I think the issue might be in the template fole (the file, that we don't see)

Comment: I just added it in my post. But you see, the reason why I want to query the blog_id of the rows I just query is because I want those blogs to be only related to the searching result.

Comment: Just to be sure.

Is this what you are doing?
`from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy`
and
`app = Flask(__name__)`
and 
`db = SQLAlchemy(app)`
? If yes it helps others to understand better your code if you add these lines to your code in the question.
If no could you add the related lines?
It just makes it easier to follow

Comment: another question. Why do you once execute a direct sql query and afterwards you perform an SqlAlchemy query?

Normally I'm used to applications that do either all queries by hand or use the ORM (SqlAlchemy) for almost everything.

Is the reason, that you did not know how to filter with SqlAlchemy?
(I never used SqlAlchemy, but if this is the case you might perhaps ask a separate question and then get rid of the direct sqlite query?)

Comment: I adapted my answer. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes! I use from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy and app = Flask(__name__) and db = SQLAlchemy(app). I'm not familiar with both query. Which type do you recommend if I'm using it to create a website?

Comment: the basic is plain sql queries. In any case it is good to play a little with them and to have some  knowledge.

2 links as  a potential starting point:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/index.htm and https://www.guru99.com/sqlite-tutorial.html .

An ORM (SqlAlchemy, Django-ORM, ...) is a kind of an abstraction and makes code more concise and often easier to understand (thoug sometimes less efficient), but its like a new language to learn. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#querying shows you examples and you can click on sql to see corresponding sql

Comment: Thank you!! Could you also please help me out in my comment down below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand. Do you mean something like.

```
c.execute("SELECT blog_id FROM blog_post WHERE problem_name LIKE(?)", ('%' + str(form.search.data) + '%',))
results = c.fetchall()
blog_ids = [entry[0] for entry in results]
```

Comment: This works!!!! Thank you so so much!! Do you know any link for me to study about these kinds of querying sqlite database using Python? I wouldn't want to go here and ask questions every day, taking time from people :). P./s You are awesome!!

Comment: Oh, I forgot, now I have the blog_ids, is there any way for me to query them from my table BlogPost so that I can paginate them on my website? How could I put the blog_ids I just query into the codes : ````many_posts = BlogPost.query.order_by(BlogPost.date.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=10)```` or is there anyway for me to do the same thing in other way?

Comment: have to go back to work, but look at the section https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#querying you should get rid of the plain sql query and do everything with ORM (something like `query.filter(User.name.ilike('%ed%'))' or in your case 
BlogPost.query.filter(BlogPost.problem_name.like("%"+str(form.search.data) + '%').order_by(BlogPost.date.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=10)` but no time to test at the moment)

Comment: Thank you! I will learn and fix this. Good luck with your work!

Comment: Kartikeya helped me out below with this code: `many_posts = BlogPost.query.filter(BlogPost.problem_name.ilike("%" + form.search.data + "%")).order_by(BlogPost.date.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=10)` and it works!! But thank you very much for sharing your materials and helping me a lot of times!!

Comment: Hi @gelonida! I have a new question and I would greatly appreciate if you could help me: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61904126/13097721 And thank you for helping me so many times!! (If this annoys you, please tell me and I will stop doing it. Please don't report me)

Answer (score 2):

sorry to jump in late but if you want an sqlalchemy solution, then you should do something like below to get the list of ids:

```
id_list = [i[0] for i in BlogPost.query.with_entities(BlogPost.blog_id ).filter(BlogPost.problem_name.ilike("%" + form.search.data  + "%")).all()]
```

Also, I think for security reasons, you should use an ORM rather than the pure SQL Query!

Comment: Thank you! No, it's fine. We all are busy and I greatly appreciate for your help:) Do you recommend me using sqlalchemy over using pure SQL Query?

Comment: Also, if you have some free time. Could you help me with this similar one? So, now I have the list of ids, is there any way for me to query data that belong to those id from my table BlogPost so that I can paginate them on my website? How could I put the blog_ids I just query into the codes : many_posts = BlogPost.query.order_by(BlogPost.date.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=10) or is there anyway for me to do the same thing in other way?   Thank you!!

Comment: just add this before order by ```.filter(BlogPost.problem_name.ilike("%" + form.search.data  + "%"))```

Comment: Wow!!! Awesome!! It works!!! Thank you so much!!, I wish I could have give you some reputation. (but I can't with my level right now) :)

Comment: Umm.. Kartikeya, if I also want my column "text" to be filter together with my column "prolem_name", could I write `.filter(BlogPost.problem_name,text.ilike("%" + form.search.data + "%"))`?   Thank you so much for helping me multiple times!

Comment: Depends if you are trying to do ```and``` or ```or``` filter. For example, if you want to do '''or'''. You can import ```from sqlalchemy import or_```. And then ```.filter(or_((BlogPost.problem_name.ilike("%" + form.search.data + "%")),(BlogPost.text.ilike("%" + form.search.data + "%")))```

Comment: Nice! So if I want to use and, I need to import and_. and just changed it with the location you put the or_ ?   (Again, thank you so much for taking your time to help me!)

Comment: great. I never used SqlAlchemy and would have needed a little more time to set up a small test to validate the correct syntax / expressions.

In an ideal world you would have worked with pure SQL queries to learn more about it's basic principles and only then switch to ORM, but being pragmatic and for your code, probably best to use ORM only. What can be interesting is (for debugging and learning to ask SqlAlchemy to display you the queries it constructed) I think this should be possible. At least it is possible with Django ORM.

Comment: Hi Kartikeya! I have a new question and I would greatly appreciate if you could help me: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61904126/13097721 And thank you for helping me so many times!!  (If this annoys you, please tell me and I will stop doing it. Please don't report me)