# How can I query and get data from my sqlite database even when my search input have similar words that is apart from each other (not continuously)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a blog search function on my website.

This is my search input: children lazy

I have a column in my SQLite database that is called: Children is getting lazy

I use the codes(Python) below to query the data:

```
many_posts0 = BlogPost.query.filter(or_((BlogPost.problem_name.ilike("%" + form.search.data + "%")),(BlogPost.text.ilike("%" + form.search.data + "%")))).order_by(BlogPost.date.desc())
```

However using the codes above, I cannot shows the result of the column "Children is getting lazy" with the search input "children lazy". If I make my search result as "children is", the column's data will show. I wonder if my problem is because of "ilike" in my query codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split the sraach string by white space and join with '%'

```
# split words and join with "%"
search_string = "%" + "%".join(search_data.split()) + "%"
many_posts0 = BlogPost.query.filter(or_((BlogPost.problem_name.ilike(search_string)),(BlogPost.text.ilike("%" + form.search.data + "%")))).order_by(BlogPost.date.desc())
```

Comment: Hi @gelonida! Thank you so much for helping me multiple times! I would greatly appreciate if you could help me with my new problems: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62373393/13097721 (And please don't report me if this annoys you... Just tell me and I will stop doing this.)

Comment: Fine with me Upchanges . SO doesn't have  any official ways to allow private messages between users if they want to (at least none, that I'm aware of). So until I can identify a 'cleaner' more official solution just continue doing this. If I don't react to a new suggested question, then assume it's either because I'm busy or because I don't know the answer. If I want you to stop I will tell you explicitly. Happy coding.

**To all:**  If anybody else knows a better way to handle this, then please tell me and upchanges, so that we don't pollute the comments channel.
I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Thank you @gelonida!!