# I just ALTER my sqlite table and added a column through my console; How do I add this command into my Python file or migration file?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlite database. I just ALTER the table called "User", adding a new column (INTEGER type) called "email_confirmed" **through the console of my sqlite database**.

My command was:

```
ALTER users ADD COLUMN email_confirmed INTEGER;
```

[image]

However, because I still don't add it through Python codes in my models.py, I couldn't use that variable "email_confirmed" in my program.
[image]

**My codes (models.py) are below.**

I'm struggling with this and if I couldn't fix this problem, I couldn't move on to another area... I would greatly appreciate it if you could show me what I should add, fix, or write, in the models.py, terminal, so that I could start using my email_confirmed variable.

-Models.py

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    profile_image = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False, default='default_profile.jpg' ) #nullable means "it cannot be blank"
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True) #DON'T REALLY GET THE IDEA OF index=True
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    middle_name = db.Column(db.String(20), default='', nullable=True)
    username = first_name+middle_name+last_name
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    # email_confirmed = db.Column(db.Integer, server_default='1', nullable=False)
    #Should I add the codes above?


    def __init__(self,email,first_name, middle_name, last_name, password,{#email_confirmed#}):    
        self.email = email
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.middle_name = middle_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)
        #self.email_confirmed = email_confirmed
```

P.s/ When I wrote the codes that I commented out in the codes above and do the migration of the database, my terminal says: "ERROR [root] Error: Target database is not up to date."

Also, somehow, if I flask db upgrade my current migration version to the one in the picture below, I will remove the new column "email_confirmed" I added through the console.

It also seems like the "ALTER ...ADD COLUMN" command I did is shown as the code below in the migration file:

```
op.add_column('users', sa.Column('email_confirmed', sa.INTEGER(), nullable=True))
```

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your project should have a `migrations` folder which is where you should have done the `ALTER TABLE` sql. Also, if you want to use `server_default='1', nullable=False`, you should set a non-null value in the DB during your migration.

Comment: Thank you for your help! As I already did ALTER TABLE in my console and not in the migrations folder. What should I do now? There is a migration version that lets me upgrade and do the following: ````op.drop_column('users', 'email_confirmed') ```,   and when I downgrade, it do the following:  ```op.add_column('users', sa.Column('email_confirmed', sa.INTEGER(), nullable=True))````

Comment: @PeacefulJames, thank you so much for your help. Do you know what "op" means in op.add_column?

Comment: `op` is the alembic "Operation" module. Did you get it working yet?

Comment: No, I'm still having the problem... I'm trying to figure it out...

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is, that Django expects to be in control of the database.

**How things should normally be done with Django:**

1. You create the model and Django will create the table.
2. You modify a model,
3. You should create a migration and apply the migration, which will in turn apply all the required database changes.

Changing the database and then modifying the model is asking for trouble, as some subtle parameters might be missing in your manual alter table.

There are several ways to *solve* the issue.

**1.) Change model, alter table manually, and perform a fake migration**

- Manually alter the table to **exactly** the same state as Django would have done
- apply a fake migration

**2.) dump old data, change model, create new DB and import / copy data.**

- create a full dump of your current database
- delete it (or for sqlite just rename the db file)
- edit `models.py`
- create a new empty database with Django `manage.py migrate`)
- try to restore your dump to the newly created database. (if field names and field types are the same this should work)

If you have any issue with the migration files created by Django and your code is only running on one server, then just delete all the migration files (**and delete also all the related .pyc files in the `__pycache__` directories**) and recreate an initial migration from scratch.

Please tell us exactly about the current status.

**Addendum 20200723:**

It might help if you post the exact current schema of your current database file.

You can do this with

```
sqlite3 databasefile.db ".schema users"
```

Comment: Thank you so much @gelonida! You always know what I'm wrong and know how to help me, and I appreciate your help very much. Just as you said, I was asking for trouble. Next time, before I do something new with my database, I will go here and ask first:) But, which way, way 1 or way 2, do you think would be easier and would have a lower chance of causing more trouble?

Comment: if the data is not too confidential, could you do following from a command  line
`sqlite3 yourdbfile ".dump users"` > table.dump and post the first few lines of table.dump here.
You can anonymize the values if necessary. If I have a partial  example dump, I can try out something and it should help me to give the best advice in your exact context.

Comment: Thank you @gelonida! I'm fixing it using your advice!

Comment: Hii @gelonida! I stored a full version of my codes that has the migration version before I alter the table on Github. Do you think it would be easier for me to go there and clone another full project? Or would a rollback of Git work of VCS return my database to its normal states? (I shared some photos that may help with your answer down below)

Answer (score 1):

These pics below are for @gelonida

My current migration version is at New Life 10 and somehow if I upgrade it to version NewLife 11, it will from the email_confirmed column. Will this works for both my model and database of "users" table? I just wanted to fix this mistake, go back to where I was right and do it right again. And thank you so much for helping me!

[image]

[image]

[image]